# Complex query in RoR Active Record including WHERE IN and AVG()

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am quite new in RoR and am experiencing a lot of problems to write my sql queries. I try to do them without (or with just a few) sql.

Here is the query I am trying to write.

```
select AVG(results.value)as 'avg', form_rows.id, form_rows.domtype 
from form_rows
join results on results.form_row_id = form_rows.id 
where form_rows.form_id = '9' and form_rows.domtype IN ('numfield', 'percentagefield')
group by results.form_row_id
```

Note, in the first where condition (form_rows.form_id = '9'), the value is send as a parameter.

If anyone can help me :)

Comment: ... I'm assuming it's giving you an error because you're using a `GROUP BY` clause, but most of your columns aren't in aggregates/listed in the `GROUP BY`.  You need to do that for every column in your `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a FormRow and Result Model

```
FormRow.joins(:results).where(:form_id => params[:form_id])
.where("form_rows.domtype IN(?)", ['numfield', 'percentagefield'])
.group("results.form_row_id")
.select("AVG(results.value) as 'avg', form_rows.id, form_rows.domtype")
```

I did not test it but that should be it

By the way: you should group by form_rows.domtype as well if you use it in your select.

Comment: wow, this is impressive. Well, it almost works. I have a result that looks good but I don't have the avg field in the results ([#<FormRow id: 33, domtype: "numfield">, #<FormRow id: 35, domtype: "numfield">, #<FormRow id: 36, domtype: "numfield">...]. Any idea why?

Comment: maybe using results.first.avg returns what you need? maybe you need an attr_accessor on the model to access that ( attr_accessor :avg ) Not quite sure right now

Comment: There is space missing in the AVG sql part: AVG(results.value) as 'avg'

Comment: well, your first comment was the good one. The query works, the result in the console does not display the avg but it is here and I can access it :) Thanks a lot!